# Connect NFC to Galaxy S5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, nfc

I have a Galaxy S5 and 6 NFC chips:
[image: NFC chips]

I want to write text to those NFC chips. I've already tried 2 apps: NFC Tools and Trigger. None of these apps hadn't recognized those NFC chips.

How can I read these NFC chips and write text on it through my Galaxy S5 device?

Answer (score 0):

They seem like ordinary RFID chips. (I want to make emphasis on "LOOKS LIKE", cause I cant tell for sure).

NFC operates on 13.56Mhz and those seem like ordinary RFID tags (125KHZ tags, with no memory)

I could be wrong since form factor, is not the only matter to identify them. They also could be an NFC tag not compatible with your phone, but they should come up saying "tag not compatible".

Have you tried: NFC tools, its a free app from the market, It could get some information out of it, if not: IT LOOKS  like a regular RFID tag. (do you have the link for those tags, from where you bought them?)